# How to SUM result both SUMs SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Using this query I try to sum result of both SUM function:

```
select 
DAY(created_at) AS day, 
SUM(if(status = '1', 1, 0)) AS result, 
SUM(if(status = '2', 1, 0)) AS noresult,
SUM(result + noresult)
from `clients` where `doctor_id` = 2 and MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) group by `day`
```

I try to do that in this line:

```
SUM(result + noresult)
```

Comment: why don't you wrap the query around another query doing the SUM(result + noresult)

Comment: use `SUM(if(status = '1', 1, 0)) + SUM(if(status = '2', 1, 0))` instead of aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As several other people have stated, you cannot use aliases in your select statement. However, to keep it cleaner, you could combine both conditions rather than summing both `SUM` fields.

```
select 
DAY(created_at) AS day, 
SUM(if(status = '1', 1, 0)) AS result, 
SUM(if(status = '2', 1, 0)) AS noresult,
SUM(if(status = '1' OR status = '2', 1, 0)) AS newcolumn
from `clients` where `doctor_id` = 2 and MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) group by `day`
```

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn's answer might be cleaner if you wanted to add more than two of these together.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select 
    DAY(created_at) AS day, 
    SUM(if(status = '1', 1, 0)) AS result, 
    SUM(if(status = '2', 1, 0)) AS noresult,
    SUM(if(status in ('1', '2'), 1, 0)) 
from `clients` 
where `doctor_id` = 2 and MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
group by `day`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use alias in select columns name  you must repeat the code

```
select 
DAY(created_at) AS day, 
SUM(if(status = '1', 1, 0)) AS result, 
SUM(if(status = '2', 1, 0)) AS noresult,
SUM(if(status = '1', 1, 0)) + SUM(if(status = '2', 1, 0)) AS all_result

from `clients` where `doctor_id` = 2 and MONTH(created_at) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) group by `day`
```

you must repeat the code because the different  SQL clause are processed  in a specific order  (first from  then where then select and and group by  .... etc..  ) so at the moment of the select parsing the alias  are not available to  the sql engine

Comment: Admit, it look awful

Comment: @OPV   . could be  but the SQL clause are processed  in a specific order  (first from  then where then select and and group by  .... etc..  ) so at the moment of the select parsing the alias  are not available to  the sql engine